# How can i achieve this result in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause

So i have this table

```
transaction_id  payment_type    status_code
1                  CASH            NULL
2                  DEBIT           200
3                  DEBIT           201
```

I want to select the data above with this condition

- `payment_type` = cash
- if `payment_type` not cash choose the data with `status_code` = 200

so the result is

```
transaction_id  payment_type    status_code
1                  CASH            NULL
2                  DEBIT           200
```

Here is what i do

```
SELECT * FROM transaction_tbl where  (payment_type = 'cash' or (payment_type IS NOT 'cash' and status_code = 200) )
```

with that query i get this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''cash' and status_code = 200) ) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2

How can i fix it ? thanks in advance

Comment: `transaction` is a MySQL keyword, don't use it as a table/column name.

Comment: Change IS NOT to `<>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your `where` clause:

```
where payment_type = 'cash' or (payment_type IS NOT 'cash' and status_code = 200)
```

`IS` is supported in operator `IS [NOT] NULL`, but not againts literal values. You want the inequality operator instead:

```
where payment_type = 'cash' or (payment_type <> 'cash' and status_code = 200)
```

However, you can simplify the logic. This does the same thing:

```
where payment_type = 'cash' or status_code = 200
```